# Stream Analytics UDF works in Test but not in Job

Tags: azure, t-sql, azure-application-insights, azure-stream-analytics

I need to parse a JSON data in Stream Analytics,

Below is the sample is am using,

```
SELECT
     UDF.parseData(GetRecordPropertyValue(GetArrayElement(A.message,0), 'raw')).intent as 'rawData'
FROM
    AppInsightMessages A
```

I can able to parse the intent from the field. This is a custom logging required.

However it is not working in Stream analytics job.

I am getting error like

```
Stream Analytics job has validation errors: Query compilation error: Expression is not supported: 'udf . parseData
```

Tried with `CAST` ing to string to record also. no luck.

What I am doing wrong  ? 
thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 1):

Usually, this is due to trying to merge multiple stages into a single expression.

Please try splitting the processing to several steps:

```
With UDFStep AS (
SELECT
    UDF.parseData(GetRecordPropertyValue(GetArrayElement(A.message,0), 'raw'))
FROM
    AppInsightMessages A
)

SELECT intent as rawData
FROM UDFStep
```

BTW, you don't need to quote the 'rawData'.

Comment: Thanks, I tried but still it is showing the same UDF error. Not sure why it is not recognizing at stream jobs.

Comment: Try extracting GetArrayElement(A.message,0) to a separate step then, and then apply the GetRecordPropertyValue and the UDF as another step. Or even split these 2.

Comment: GetArrayElement used to work with object, but these are string values. So I made changes in code to send objects and used GetRecordPropertyValue + GetArrayElements as of now . 
But still the string conversion is required for my case .